How to make exception on DNS Forwarder for a DNS entry
We have a Windows DNS server and we added a forwarder to pass the DNS lookup of the domain  abc.com.
However, we want a single DNS record host1.abc.com to map to a specific IP address that is different than the DNS lookup result from the forwarder DNS server.
Base on my understanding, I need to create a Forward Lookup Zone for abc.com on my local DNS server, and then add only one host1.abc.com DNS record in it.
However, if I added the abc.com domain in my local DNS server Forward Lookup Zones, every DNS query of *.abc.com will not pass to the forwarder, and this is not what I want.
How can I configure the local DNS server so that I can add a single DNS record host1.abc.com for my local user to lookup while passing all the other abc.com queries to the forwarder?

Create a DNS zone for host1.example.com (use your actual FQDN of the host) and add an A record at the root for the ip address you want it to resolve to.


